# Communicating Between Two Devices When One Lacks Internet Access

Tags: network, wireless, internet

I am currently developing a software that needs to establish communication between two devices. Device 1 has internet capabilities, while device 2 may not always have internet access. I am investigating the possibility of using satellite communication to overcome this limitation. This would enable device 2 to receive data no matter where it is located or whether it has internet connectivity.

Does anyone have experience or knowledge about utilizing satellite communication for this purpose? Specifically, I'm curious about:

- The possibility of sending data from device 1 to device 2 via satellite.
- The necessary hardware requirements for both sending and receiving data.
- Options available for leveraging satellite communication without the need to launch my own satellite.

---

I have a basic understanding of communication technology, but I'm not familiar with the specifics of satellite communication. I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or resources on how to learn about satellite communication or other communication methods suitable for similar situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For device A to talk with device B, there must be a communications channel between them. The Internet is one such channel -- the most common, and easiest. That could also be a direct ethernet cable, serial (RS-232) cable, or even a flashing LED (IrDA).

When you mention satellite, there's a similar range of options: Starlink, HughesNet, BGAN, direct RF transponder, etc. The latter is the most complex (and expensive.) I'll assume you want one of the former; in which case, we're back to just connecting to the internet. Starlink will be the simplest of them all -- take it out of the box, give it power and a clear view of the sky, and it'll figure everything out. Hughesnet needs professional installation. BGAN needs a bit of practice to aim, and a *huge* clear view of the southern sky. (depending on where you are... to the equatorial orbit)